# Nvidia control panel alternative

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

There was a software which allows the user to edit per-executable nvidia settings and allows user to unlocks old applications to use the nvidia graphics instead of Intel GPU. Can you give me names of software which does that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself, it's [Nvidia Inspector](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-inspector-download.html), it can override Nvidia Optimus and force applications to Nvidia GPU on all processes.

Comment: How nice. This was useful for me today.